# Google APIs Client Library for PHP - countryBlocked exception

Tags: php, api, google-api-php-client, country

I've created a web application which runs with the 'Google APIs Client Library'.

This worked perfectly for me for the last two years.
But since yesterday I am facing a huge problem.

If I want to access the analytics api the system returns:

```
Google_Service_Exception Object
(
[errors:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [domain] => global
                [reason] => countryBlocked
                [message] => This service is not available from your region
            )

    )

    [retryMap:Google_Service_Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [500] => -1
        [503] => -1
        [rateLimitExceeded] => -1
        [userRateLimitExceeded] => -1
    )

    [message:protected] => Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles: (403) This service is not available from your region
)
```

I've checked the logs and made 50 requests the last 30 days so spamming could not be the reason for the block.

When I run it from a different Server it runs just fine.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can bypass it?

Comment: The server is hosted in germany, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Check out https://www.quora.com/Is-Google-Analytics-really-illegal-in-Germany